# Need help to understand second line in pom.xml <project xmlns=...>

Tags: maven, pom.xml

On Maven project, I kind of know of purpose pom.xml but still not fully understand  why we need this line
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" >

Hope someone help to give details explain in plain english.

Thanks.

Comment: spend quite time google and still not find clarity answer. From my .02, this is just declare project conform standard as mentioned on link.

Comment: From [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_pom.htm] secondline in pom.xml can be understand as project root tag and conform schema settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this question will be downvoted a lot, but nevertheless: With this you define the XML-schema which is used to define the structure which your xml file must have to be valid.

You could for example try and call the URL for the XSD in the browser and you will see how and what the XSD validates. That is not a Maven specific thing but generally a good idea if you use XML files. Google for XSD and read some tutorials to better understand this.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I actually don't care much about down voted rather than keep confusing myself with something that I need to understand.

Comment: Same with me, but you could mark the answer as solution so the other users won't look at it so much as it is already answered and they don't have to care anymore :-)